# Algorithm to create all edges between a bunch of nodes in a 3d space?

Tags: java, path, 3d, game-development, path-finding

I have a bunch of points in a 3d environment that I want to solve the traveling salesman problem with, for that I first need to convert the game world to a graph.

The world is around 1km wide, 1.5 km long and 250m high = 375 000 000 possible location. Each location either has an obstacle or is walkable.

There are 150 location that I want to connect in this world. What would be the best approach to solve this?

Here is how the pathfinder looks right now, which is the bidirectional a* that also takes into account telporters

```
package me.mmaxi.pathfinder;

import me.mmaxi.utils.Location;
import me.mmaxi.utils.TeleportDirection;

import java.util.*;

public class PathFinder {
private final Map<Location, Block> blocks = new HashMap<>();

public List<Location> getPath(Location start, Location goal, IWalkHandler walkHandler, ITeleportHandler teleportHandler) {
    // initializing start queue
    PriorityQueue<PathFindStep> queueFromStart = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Block startBlock = getBlock(start);
    startBlock.distanceFromStart = 0;
    startBlock.fScore = start.h(goal, teleportHandler, TeleportDirection.FORWARD);
    queueFromStart.add(new PathFindStep(startBlock, startBlock.fScore));
    // initializing goal queue
    PriorityQueue<PathFindStep> queueFromGoal = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Block goalBlock = getBlock(goal);
    goalBlock.distanceFromGoal = 0;
    goalBlock.fScore = goal.h(start, teleportHandler, TeleportDirection.BACKWARD);
    queueFromGoal.add(new PathFindStep(goalBlock, goalBlock.fScore));
    // here we will store the meeting point
    Block meetingPoint = null;
    // for debug purposes
    int furthestAwayFromStartSoFar = 0;
    int furthestAwayFromGoalSoFar = 0;
    // working on the queues
    while (!queueFromStart.isEmpty() || !queueFromGoal.isEmpty()) {
        // coming from start
        PathFindStep currentStepFromStart = queueFromStart.poll();
        if (currentStepFromStart == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("We can no longer reach any blocks from the start. Maybe it's inside a wall?");
        } else {
            Block current = currentStepFromStart.toVisit;
            if (Double.compare(currentStepFromStart.fScore, current.fScore) != 0) {
                // we already found a better fScore in the meantime
                continue;
            }
            if (current.location.equals(goal) || current.lastComingFromGoal != null) {
                // we found the goal or meeting point
                System.out.println("Breaking condition:\n" +
                        "* current.location.equals(goal):" + current.location.equals(goal) + "\n" +
                        "* current.lastComingFromGoal != null:" + (current.lastComingFromGoal != null));
                meetingPoint = current;
                break;
            }
            Set<Block> neighbours = getNeighbours(current);
            Location teleportTarget = teleportHandler.getDestination(current.location);
            if (teleportTarget != null) {
                System.out.println("Found teleport target: " + teleportTarget);
                neighbours.add(getBlock(teleportTarget));
            }
            for (Block neighbour : neighbours) {
                if (!walkHandler.canWalk(neighbour.location) && !neighbour.location.equals(goal)) {
                    // we can't go there so ignoring this neighbour but only if it's not the goal
                    continue;
                }
                int pendingDistanceFromStart = current.distanceFromStart + 1;
                if (pendingDistanceFromStart < neighbour.distanceFromStart) {
                    neighbour.lastComingFromStart = current;
                    neighbour.distanceFromStart = pendingDistanceFromStart;
                    neighbour.fScore = neighbour.location.h(goal, teleportHandler, TeleportDirection.FORWARD) + pendingDistanceFromStart;
                    queueFromStart.add(new PathFindStep(neighbour, neighbour.fScore));
                    if (pendingDistanceFromStart > furthestAwayFromStartSoFar) {
                        furthestAwayFromStartSoFar = pendingDistanceFromStart;
                        if (pendingDistanceFromStart % 25 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Furthest from start: " + pendingDistanceFromStart);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // coming from goal
        PathFindStep currentStepFromGoal = queueFromGoal.poll();
        if (currentStepFromGoal == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("We can no longer reach any blocks from the goal. Maybe it's inside a wall?");
        } else {
            Block current = currentStepFromGoal.toVisit;
            if (Double.compare(currentStepFromGoal.fScore, current.fScore) != 0) {
                // we already found a better fScore in the meantime
                continue;
            }
            if (current.location.equals(start) || current.lastComingFromStart != null) {
                // we found the start or meeting point
                System.out.println("Breaking condition:\n" +
                        "* current.location.equals(start):" + current.location.equals(start) + "\n" +
                        "* current.lastComingFromStart != null:" + (current.lastComingFromStart != null));
                meetingPoint = current;
                break;
            }
            Set<Block> neighbours = getNeighbours(current);
            Location teleportStart = teleportHandler.getStart(current.location);
            if (teleportStart != null) {
                System.out.println("Found teleport start: " + teleportStart);
                neighbours.add(getBlock(teleportStart));
            }
            for (Block neighbour : neighbours) {
                if (!walkHandler.canWalk(neighbour.location) && !neighbour.location.equals(start)) {
                    // we can't go there so ignoring this neighbour but only if it's not the start
                    continue;
                }
                int pendingDistanceFromGoal = current.distanceFromGoal + 1;
                if (pendingDistanceFromGoal < neighbour.distanceFromGoal) {
                    neighbour.lastComingFromGoal = current;
                    neighbour.distanceFromGoal = pendingDistanceFromGoal;
                    neighbour.fScore = neighbour.location.h(start, teleportHandler, TeleportDirection.BACKWARD) + pendingDistanceFromGoal;
                    queueFromGoal.add(new PathFindStep(neighbour, neighbour.fScore));
                    if (pendingDistanceFromGoal > furthestAwayFromGoalSoFar) {
                        furthestAwayFromGoalSoFar = pendingDistanceFromGoal;
                        if (pendingDistanceFromGoal % 25 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Furthest from goal: " + pendingDistanceFromGoal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (meetingPoint == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find a meeting point.");
    }
    System.out.println("Found a meeting point! " + meetingPoint.location);
    // reversing the one side coming from the goal, so we can then backtrack
    System.out.println("Reversing side that started from goal.");
    while (meetingPoint.lastComingFromGoal != null) {
        meetingPoint.lastComingFromGoal.lastComingFromStart = meetingPoint;
        meetingPoint = meetingPoint.lastComingFromGoal;
    }
    // now we can backtrack
    System.out.println("Backtracking.");
    Block tmp = goalBlock;
    if (tmp.lastComingFromStart == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find the target block from that start block.");
    }
    System.out.println("Found goal. Starting to backtrack.");
    List<Location> path = new ArrayList<>();
    while (tmp != null) {
        path.add(tmp.location);
        tmp = tmp.lastComingFromStart;
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

private Block getBlock(Location location) {
    return blocks.computeIfAbsent(location, block -> new Block(location));
}

private Set<Block> getNeighbours(Block block) {
    Set<Block> neighbours = new HashSet<>();
    for (BlockFace blockFace : BlockFace.values()) {
        Location targetLocation = block.location.clone().add(blockFace.vector);
        if (targetLocation.getBlockY() > 255 || targetLocation.getBlockY() < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        neighbours.add(getBlock(targetLocation));
    }
    return neighbours;
}

static class PathFindStep implements Comparable<PathFindStep> {
    Block toVisit;
    double fScore;

    public PathFindStep(Block toVisit, double fScore) {
        this.toVisit = toVisit;
        this.fScore = fScore;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PathFindStep o) {
        return Double.compare(fScore, o.fScore);
    }
}

static class Block {
    Location location;

    Block lastComingFromStart;
    Block lastComingFromGoal;
    double fScore;
    int distanceFromStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int distanceFromGoal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public Block(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

enum BlockFace {
    POS_Y(new Location(+0, +1, +0)),
    NEG_Y(new Location(+0, -1, +0)),
    POS_X(new Location(+1, +0, +0)),
    NEG_X(new Location(-1, +0, +0)),
    POS_Z(new Location(+0, +0, +1)),
    NEG_Z(new Location(+0, +0, -1));

    final Location vector;

    BlockFace(Location vector) {
        this.vector = vector;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Location implements Cloneable {
private double x, y, z;

public Location(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public double getZ() {
    return z;
}

public int getBlockX() {
    return (int) x;
}

public int getBlockY() {
    return (int) y;
}

public int getBlockZ() {
    return (int) z;
}

public Location add(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.z += z;
    return this;
}

public Location add(Location other) {
    this.x += other.x;
    this.y += other.y;
    this.z += other.z;
    return this;
}

public double distanceSquared(Location other) {
    double dx = x - other.x;
    double dy = y - other.y;
    double dz = z - other.z;
    return dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
}

public double mhd(Location other) {
    double dx = Math.abs(x - other.x);
    double dy = Math.abs(y - other.y);
    double dz = Math.abs(z - other.z);
    return Math.max(dx, Math.max(dy, dz));
}

public double h(Location other, ITeleportHandler teleportHandler, TeleportDirection teleportDirection) {
    double h = mhd(other);
    if (teleportHandler != null) {
        Location[] closestTeleport = teleportHandler.getClosestTeleport(this, teleportDirection);
        if (closestTeleport != null) {
            if (teleportDirection == TeleportDirection.FORWARD) {
                h = Math.min(h, mhd(closestTeleport[0]) + closestTeleport[1].mhd(other));
            } else {
                h = Math.min(h, mhd(closestTeleport[1]) + closestTeleport[0].mhd(other));
            }
        }
    }
    return h;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Location location = (Location) o;
    return Double.compare(location.x, x) == 0 && Double.compare(location.y, y) == 0 && Double.compare(location.z, z) == 0;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y, z);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String xString = Double.compare(x, (int) x) == 0 ? Integer.toString((int) x) : Double.toString(x);
    String yString = Double.compare(y, (int) y) == 0 ? Integer.toString((int) y) : Double.toString(y);
    String zString = Double.compare(z, (int) z) == 0 ? Integer.toString((int) z) : Double.toString(z);
    return "[" + xString + " " + yString + " " + zString + "]";
}

@Override
public Location clone() {
    try {
        return (Location) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Creating the graph and finding the shortest route through it are two different problems; if you're asking about the first, don't post code for the second. Do you want the shortest path between every pair of cities?